# The comment array in the Post does not show the comment id even though the Post and the Comment is linked

Tags: node.js, mongoose, post, comments

The model of Post.js is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }]
})

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)

module.exports = Post
```

The model of Comment.js is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        comment: String
})


const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema)

module.exports = Comment
```

The router of adding the comment is:

```
const express = require('express')
const Comment = require('../models/comment')
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')
const router = new express.Router()

router.post('/comments/:id', auth, async(req, res)=>{
    const comment = new Comment(req.body)
    try {
        await comment.save()
        res.status(201).send(comment)
    } catch (e){
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

The comment is sent from the Postman like below.

```
   {{url}}/comments/61ab30166760b4f9fc40060f
```

The comment Id, however, is not added to the Post as expected. The Robo 3T shows the empty array of the comments in the Post.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61ab30096760b4f9fc40060a"),
    "title" : "jstesting the blog the 1st time",
    "content" : "jstesting how the node and mongoose are interacting the 1st time",
    "postedBy" : ObjectId("61ab2fd06760b4f9fc4005f7"),
    "comments" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61ab30166760b4f9fc40060f"),
    "title" : "jstesting the blog the 2nd time",
    "content" : "jstesting how the node and mongoose are interacting the 2nd time",
    "postedBy" : ObjectId("61ab2fd06760b4f9fc4005f7"),
    "comments" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Somebody please help me find why the Comment Id is not added to the comments array of the Post.

Comment: `commentSchema` appears to only have one field - `comment` - `mongoose` has no way to know what comments relate to what posts. You'd likely need to add a `postId` field to the comment where you post the ID of the post the comment is on.

Comment: @Tetarchus Thank you for your comment but it seems it was not the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The router management was wrong. It should be as ..

```
router.post('/comments/:id', auth, async(req, res)=>{
    const comment = new Comment(req.body)
    try {
        const post = await Post.findOne({
            _id: req.params.id,
        })

        if(!post){
            return res.status(404).send()
        }
        
        post.comments.push(comment._id)

        await post.save()
        await comment.save()

        res.status(201).send(comment)
    } catch (e){
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

It may not be the best approach but at least it works.